# Spring @Around WebClient Calls

Tags: spring, kotlin, aop, spring-webflux

I'm trying to create an attribute that would validate the Captcha in a request via an attribute. The core of the problem is I can't seem to find a way to handle the asynchronous WebClient call in the `@Around()` handler

The Goal

```
@Captcha
@PostMapping(path = ["some-endpoint"])
fun doSomething(@RequestBody request: Mono<MyRequestWithCaptchaReponseField>) : Mono<MyResponse> { 
  // Endpoint Code
}
```

AOP Code

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Captcha()

@Aspect
@Component
class CaptchaAspect {
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var captchaClient: CaptchaService

  @Around("@annoation(Captcha)")
  @Throws(Throwable::class)
  fun validateCaptcha(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Mono<Any> {

     val request = joinPoint.args[0] as Mono<MyRequestWithCaptchaReponseField> // This works
     return request.map { captchaClient.isValid(it.captchaResponse } // This seems to be making the call. I would throw an exception here if the captcha was invalid
                   .flatMap { joinPoint.proceed() as Mono<Any> }

  }
}
```

This is as close as I've gotten and it almost works, but the response that's returned is a `mono<MyResponse>` and it seems that even though the controller endpoint is returning a `Mono<MyResponse>`, as an `@Around()` method it is expecting a return of just MyResponse.

The core question is, if I have to make a WebClient API call inside an `@Around()` method, how do I handle returning joinPoint.proceed after the API call is finished?

Comment: What's the problem with this? Do you get an error?

Comment: This guy actually says a response wasn't returned, which I'm kinda confused about. If I change that last flatMap to a map, then it returns a Mono and serialized that as a response. It just has a scanAvailable field

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution

```
@Aspect
@Component
class CaptchaAspect {
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var captchaClient: CaptchaService

  @Around("@annoation(Captcha)")
  @Throws(Throwable::class)
  fun validateCaptcha(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Mono<Any> {

     val request = joinPoint.args[0] as Mono<MyRequestWithCaptchaReponseField> // This works
     return joinPoint.proceed(arrayOf<Any>(request.filterWhen { r -> {
       if (r is MyRequestWithCaptchaReponseField) {
         this.captchaClient.isValid(r.captchaResponse)
       } else {
         throw Exception("Request should have a captcha field")
       }
     })
  }
}
```

ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed can take an Array that maps to the arguments of the controller action. So you can hijack arg[0], and tack on your logic before sending it on. These pipeline steps get executed before anything in the controller method. I've changed my captchaClient.isValid call to a filterWhen that always either throws an exception or returns Mono.just(true)